# nodejs socket.io action handler with a for loop

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I sincerely hope that my following question is clear.

Let's say I have 10 users connected to my server, each with a LCD touch screen display.
They have a choice to click from a selection of buttons, in which those buttons emits some data to the server. Then the server processes this data and then emits it back to certain client(s).

Each button (in my case are `<a>` tags styled to look like buttons) executes a function that looks something like the one below:

```
function emitExample(action, clickedTag){
    socket.emit(userID, {action:action, data: "data"});
}
```

Then on the server, I want to be able to handle all of these requests without "socket.broadcast.emit()" or "socket.on()" for every single request, because in the future, I will have many more users and possible requests.

Let's consider this: I need to recognize the combo user-buttonTag so I would need to have something like this:

```
    //where to add new users
    var users = {
            "user-1":"user-1",
            "user-2":"user-2",
            ...
            ...
            "user-N":"user-N"
        };

    //where to add new actions
    var actions = {
            'action-1':'action-1',
            ...
            ...
            'action-N':'action-N'
            };

    for(var action in actions)
    {
        for(var user in users)
        {
            // *** here i have the issue *** //
            events[key] = function(data)
            {
                socket.broadcast.emit(action, data);
            };
        }
    }

    // this work fine...
    for (var method in events) {
        var dynamicHandler = function (realMethod) 
        {
            socket.on(realMethod, function (data) {
                events[realMethod].apply(this, data);
            });
        };
        dynamicHandler(method);
    }
```

Around the end:

```
events[key] = function(data)
```

I would like to make all the user/action combination working, however it only retrieves the last one.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me. :)

Comment: sorry, i delete the "Hi everybody" part :)

Comment: No problem! Also I don't think it's possible to handle requests without a socket.on call or socket.broadcast.emit.

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply.

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply.
the "for cycle" works fine, my problem is on the events[method] because now is too long: if i have 5 users and 5 actions i need 25 def:
example for 'n' users and 2 actions: (left, right):
        ..........
        
        "n-right": function(data){
            socket.broadcast.emit('n-right', 'n-right');
        },
        "n-left": function(data){
            socket.broadcast.emit('n-left', 'n-left');
        }
    };`

Comment: (sorry...my problem with -code- tag)

Comment: No problem ;) I can still read it.